# org-mode: Enable ido/ivy/helm in org-tags-view

Tags: org-mode

`org-completion-use-ido` seems to enable interactive completion everywhere but not in `org-tags-view` (which is called when you choose "Match a TAGS/PROP/TODO query" in Agenda Commands).

Out-of-the-box `org-tags-view` has only the dull <TAB>-completion which is annoyingly primitive, how do I enable a proper interactive completion there?

Comment: It works without any further setup for me using selectrum. Do you have `ido-everywhere` set to `t`?

Comment: @mclear, yes, `ido-everywhere` is set to `t`, not sure why it works in all other parts of org-mode, but not here.   But thanks for a reference to selectrum, I'll try it out!

Comment: If you want to stay with something even more "native" emacs you can also try icomplete-vertical, which is basically just a series of wrappers around emacs' native icomplete: https://github.com/oantolin/icomplete-vertical